# How to use the loading boolean in the Apollo example for Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm trying to implement some sort of loading screen while waiting for the call to respond. In the Apollo client example for Angular they use a 'loading' boolean

> We can see that the result object contains loading, a Boolean indicating if the query is “in-flight”

Then they say the following, implying that loading will be set to false **automatically** when the query is complete

> The observable will only emit once when the query is complete, and loading will be set to false

I'm guessing they skipped some documentation here because my loading property will always say undefined no matter what, and it's an exact copy.

Am i missing something? I would like to know how to implement the loading boolean correctly.

Thanks!

Edit: Forgot to add the example:  http://dev.apollodata.com/angular2/queries.html